# Checking an array of booleans in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to check an array of booleans and for each value act accordingly.

Current code is something like this, but i want to make it read easier

```
If heater_check(0) = true Then

    get_temp(0)

End If

If heater_check(1) = true Then

    get_temp(1)

End If

...
```

And so on. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I did not.. :( Would there be any other way, though?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
For i As Integer = 0 To heater_check.length - 1
    If heater_check(i) then
      get_temp(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: For a case like this, could a For loop still work?



If node_num = "1" Then


            Temperature(0) = C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 22))) + C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 21))) * 16 + C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 20))) * 256


        ElseIf node_num = "2" Then


            Temperature(1) = C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 22))) + C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 21))) * 16 + C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 20))) * 256
.
.
.
.

node_num is of a Char type

Comment: As long as there is a _'pattern'_ on your variable changes, you can always use loop to simplify your `If-Else` statement

Answer (score 0):

> *"For a case like this, could a For loop still work? If node_num = "1" Then Temperature(0) = C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 22))) + C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(b........ "*
> **chia kang ren**

And the answer :

> *"As long as there is a 'pattern' on your variable changes, you can always use loop to simplify your If-Else statement"*
> **TheQuickBrownFox**

---

**..or use some logic to tie together two variables of different types having *some* sort of relation between, whenever required.**

```
    ' ...

    Dim TempIndex As Int32 = Integer.Parse(node_num) - 1
    ' Converts node_num to an Integer and substract 1.

    Temperature(TempIndex) = _
        C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 22))) + _
        C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 21))) * 16 + _
        C_D(Convert.ToChar(raw_result(byte_num + 20))) * 256

    ' ...
```

---

By the way, if you're asking **A**, **only answers to A are relevant**, 
or answers that covers A ***and*** anything directly related to A like **A'**, **-A**, **A²** or **|A|**.

Here I'm talking about **converting a String to Integer**. That has nothing to do with :

> *"I need to check an array of booleans and for each value act accordingly."*

=> *Please mark [TheQuickBrownFox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27007149/2410892) as the valid answer. (And avoid asking other questions than the original one - :) )*